# How to show device softkeys in fullscreen

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-creator

I want to show the device's default softkeys in fullscreen window, I have tried the setWindowsFlags(), but nothing happened.
does anyone know to to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Symbian version ( IE Maemo, or actual Symbian ), this can be achieved via

showMaximized
or
showFullScreen()

Comment: Symbian is Symbian. Maemo is not related with symbian in any other way than it is Nokia's